# Usage of getSymbols from R package QUANTMOD

Tags: r, quantmod, google-finance

I would like to use `getSymbols` to get financial index data from Google finance. When I search for my indices then I get INDEXDB:RXPG for EB.REXX and INDEXDJX:DJUBS for DJ UBS.

A call of the form

`getSymbols("INDEXDJX:DJUBS",src="google",from = "2007-01-01",to = Sys.Date())`
or

`getSymbols("INDEXDB:RXPG",src="google",from = "2007-01-01",to = Sys.Date())`

does not work.

Another side question: is there any description of the symbols on google finance?

I don't think that this is necessary for my question but my session info is this:
R version 2.14.1 (2011-12-22)
Platform: x86_64-pc-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
and I use quantmod 0.4-0.

Comment: If Google does not make the data available in CSV format, there's not much quantmod can do. If you provide a URL where the data you want can be downloaded, I can patch `getSymbols.google` to use it. Also, this is a very similar question to the one you [posted on quantSE](http://quant.stackexchange.com/q/9715/56). Better to post in only one place, so you do not fragment information.

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich You are right, my cross posting is not optimal - I just thought that the audience is different ... but you are here too ;) I can geht a table for the data on yahoo, the URLs are https://www.google.com/finance/historical?cid=16381116&startdate=Jan+1%2C+2006&enddate=Dec+13%2C+2013&num=30&ei=FCCrUpj3KaXz0gHI9gE and https://www.google.com/finance/historical?cid=7472920&startdate=Jan+1%2C+2006&enddate=Dec+13%2C+2013&num=30&ei=_SqrUoiINNOs0AHxgwE

Comment: In the EB.REXX data there is a gap ... that's another problem. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Yes, I know you can view the data on the webpage; that's why I specifically said, "provide a URL where the data can be downloaded". If you want, you can try to scrape the HTML, but I'm not going to do it.

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding....I can not do it and it is clear that you don't do it. Thank you anyways.